# msvcr100.dll is missing when installing apache

Tags: php, apache, dll

I am Installing Apache HTTP Server for php 
when i run         *httpd -k start* 
it shows error "msvcr100.dll is missing"

Now i download it from microsoft site but it says
A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine.

Plz provide solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Install the C++ Redistributable Package 2010 that can be downloaded from

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26999

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the installed package and then reinstall, the installed version can be removed from the control panel. If it does not show up check the show updates button. (I am on a linux machine, but I think I have seen it somewhere)